# I want to find a best approach to using Firebase as a back-end for Android, IOS & Web Application

Tags: php, android, ios, firebase-realtime-database, backend

I need to build a application for ios, android & web with some of live data updations (Only one screen) from a calculation functions along with basic Login/Register/Profile/Contact Us/About Us/Blogs.

So I want to know best approach from following three:

1. Can we use Firebase real-time database as a secondary database for that particular live data which required to sync in real time?
2. Can we use only Firebase real-time database as a main database for all data with our traditional  approach like restful APIs with php?
3. Is it possible to use Firebase tools only as full backend development instead traditional php & Mysql/Mongo DB combination if yes what are the steps?

Tools like:
Authentication, Realtime Database, Cloud Storage, Cloud Functions & Firebase Hosting.

Comment: your question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things to consider, which is beyond the scope of what we can reasonably answer in a Stack Overflow post. I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), and also [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video). While the last one of for Firebase's other NoSQL database, many of the principles explained in it apply equally to both (and many non-Firebase) NoSQL databases.

For your concrete questions:

1. Yes. See for an example of this [Where does Firebase fit in your app?](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html) and [Build an Android App Using Firebase and the App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible).
2. The Firebase Realtime Database can be used as your primary database. Just keep in mind that Firebase is not meant to be an offline-only database. If you have an app that never connects to the server, you should consider other options.
3. Yes. I'd recommend checking out the Firebase documentation, and looking for a few tutorials.